# React seems like doesn't pass props to another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I follow a tutorial on how to build a `React` application, and I am stacked with a kind of strange issue.

When I try to pass some information to another component, the other component getting the `props` but it is empty.

In my case, the `index.js` is like that:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import YTSearch from 'youtube-api-search';

import SearchBar from './components/search_bar';
import VideoList from './components/video_list';

const API_KEY = 'AIzaSyDdvc_zComCpdqqfmwgOsZvLOwwPEabcde';

class App extends Component {
    constructor ( props ) {
        super ( props );

        this.state = {
            videos : []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        YTSearch (
            {
                key  : API_KEY,
                term : 'surfboards'
            },
            videos => {
                this.setState ( { videos } );
            }
        );
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <SearchBar />
                <VideoList videos={this.state.videos} />
            </div>
        );
    }
};

ReactDOM.render (
    <App />,
    document.querySelector ( '.container' )
);
```

and my code in the `./components/video_list.js` is like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import VideoListItem from './video_list_item';

class VideoList extends Component {
    constructor( props ) {
        super( props );

        this.state = {
            videoItems : []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState(
            {
                videoItems: this.props.videos.map(
                    video => {
                        console.log( video );
                        return <VideoListItem video={video} />;
                    }
                )
            }
        )
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ul className="col-md-4 list-group">{ this.state.videoItems }</ul>
        );
    }
}

export default VideoList;
```

The code seems to be very strateforward, but in reality it has issues.

If I try this statement `console.log( this.state.videos );` before the `return` statement in the `index.js` I get the following output:

```
// Initially I get this because the API is not yet completed:
Array[0]
    length: 0
    __proto__: Array[0]

// And then, once the API Request it is completed I get this:
Array[5]
    0: Object
        etag : ""5C5HHOaBSHC5ZXfkrT4ZlRCi01A/2H00YaVLWV4Xof09xk9Q8k6vlxw""
        id: Object
        kind: "youtube#searchResult"
        snippet: Object
        __proto__: Object
    1: Object
    2: Object
    3: Object
    4: Object
    length: 5
    __proto__: Array[0]
```

At the same time if I try a `console.log( props )` inside the `constructor` method of the `VideoList` component I get the following output:

```
Object {videos: Array[0]}
    videos: Array[0]
        length: 0
        __proto__: Array[0]
    __proto__: Object
```

Do you have any idea of what can be wrong ? Do you see something I don't see ?

Comment: that looks correct to me since you log the props in constructor. React component has a lifecycle [https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html). if you expect to see the props passed down, it's during the updating lifecycle such as `componentWillReceiveProps()`

Comment: @phoa thank you for your answer. I am going to check the `componentWillReceiveProps` and I will update you :)

Comment: @phoa thank you :) That worked for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding this -

At the same time if I try a console.log( props ) inside the constructor method of the `VideoList` component I get the following output:

```
Object {videos: Array[0]}
    videos: Array[0]
        length: 0
        __proto__: Array[0]
    __proto__: Object
```

This is absolutely correct behaviour.

This is happening because during react component life cycle your child component gets rendered first and at that time props which you are passing to your child component will be having default or empty values ( e.g []).

Now your child gets rendered the parent rendering happens.

When parent gets rendered completely `componentDidMount` method of parent gets called in which you have made some ajax request to download dynamic data which in your case is video lists.

Which you are doing like this and this is also perfectly valid -

```
componentDidMount() {
    YTSearch (
        {
            key  : API_KEY,
            term : 'surfboards'
        },
        videos => {
            this.setState ( { videos } );
        }
    );
}
```

After the data comes in via `ajax` you set the state again in your parent component which causes rendering cycle to happen again.

```
            this.setState ( { videos } );
```

Now your child will receive updated new video list array.

And rendering of child happens again which will be having video lists.

But since you have parent props changed and to receive new props you need to add a new life cycle method.

```
componentWillReceiveProps
```

Here you can compare `old props` with `new props` and set the states to the updated props. Which will render the child component with latest updated data.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.setState(
            {
                videoItems: nextProps.videos.map(
                    video => {
                        console.log( video );
                        return <VideoListItem video={video} />;
                    }
                )
            }
        )
}
```

Comment: first thank you for the answer. Once the parent component it is get the data via Ajax it set again the new state of it self. In this case, don't you think it should update the child as well ? If I have understand this well, once the state of a parent element changes, the child should get updated as well. Or I am wrong ? :?

Answer (score 0):

In "./components/video_list.js"

Instead of setting state on **componentDidMount** use **componentWillReceiveProps()**

OR
 in index.js

```
const API_KEY = 'AIzaSyDdvc_zComCpdqqfmwgOsZvLOwwPEabcde';

class App extends Component {
    constructor ( props ) {
        super ( props );

        this.state = {
            videos : []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        YTSearch (
            {
                key  : API_KEY,
                term : 'surfboards'
            },
            videos => {
                this.setState ( { videos } );
            }
        );
    }

    render () {
        const { videos } = this.state
        return (
            <div>
                <SearchBar />

                {videos.length ?
                    <VideoList videos={this.state.videos} />
                : null
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
};

ReactDOM.render (
    <App />,
    document.querySelector ( '.container' )
);
```